# Forcibly Uninstalling Eclipse 3.5 Plugins

Tags: android, eclipse

How do you forcibly uninstall Eclipse 3.5 plugins **without using Eclipse**? I made the mistake of installing Google's Android SDK, and now when I try to check for updates via the "Check For Updates" or "Install New Software", some Android process runs, consumes all my CPU, takes up 3 gigs of memory, and crashes Eclipse. I can't even get to the uninstall dialog before Google's plugin kills everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing that you can try, is to go to your Eclipse directory, then "plugins" directory. There, remove the files and folders which are related to your SDK.

To find the concerned files, you should download the plugin file at [this link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#troubleshooting). By checking the content of this archive, you will know exactly what files got installed, and what you should delete.

It's a bit extreme, and you can possibly prevent other things from working if you remove too much, so I recommend you to back this folder prior to doing so.

There might be some configurations remaining, and some unstable state of the plugin, instead of its complete removal, but it could be enough for you to be able to open Eclipse, and remove it properly.

Note that some plugins have configuration files installed in the workspace you use, in the .metadata/.plugins folder.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't try this in this case, but I've fixed similar problems this way in the past. Fortunately, I managed to perform a total Eclipse update before the SDK killed everything, and that seems to have fixed whatever bug was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse, go to Window --> Preferences --> Install/Update --> Click on Uninstall or update link, then choose the plugin you want to remove.